# how can I wrap a click event in a function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to set click event in if condition

```
var clicked = $('#navs li').click; // but this is clicked automatically
```

How could I do?

I wanted to do like this

```
if(clicked){
/*code in here*/
}
```

I have a problem with .on('click'), .trigger('click') and something else I'm searching something like if event type = click.

Comment: why you need this when you have an event that is clicked or not

Comment: Sorry, but what are you looking for? I don't get it! You want to know if click event is defined for an element or what?

Comment: Yes but I tested within .on('click') function which is giving me wrong result so I want to check something like event.type = click I don't know about this

Comment: `if($._data($('#element').get(0),'events').click)` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean:

```
$('#navs li').click(function() {
   console.log("i m clicked");
});
```

then do you mean like, storing click'ed in some [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('#navs li').click(function() {
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
//and
if($('#navs li').data('clicked')) {
    alert("yes, i'm clicked already");
}
```

Comment: @C-Link check the added answer, do you mean something like that..?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use .on():

```
$('#navs li').on('click', function(){
 //code here
});
```

And just add the code you want to run that was going in the if. You don't need an if condition, the only time the code will execute is if the element was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To check if event click jquery handler is defined for an element, you can use not publicly supported method `$._data()`

```
if($._data($('#element').get(0),'events').click)
```

The first parameter is a DOM node, not jquery object.